# Minimum using Jayway JsonPath

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am trying to find minimum of specific values from give json using JsonPath.

Given following json(taken from [here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book.length()])):

```
   {
    "store": {
        "book": [{
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        }, {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }]
    },
    "expensive": 10
  }
```

I am trying to find out minimum of all book prices. So basically I am expecting :

```
     min(8.99,22.99) = 8.99
```

By looking at examples from [jsonPath github page](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) about functions, I tried following expression, but it don't seem to work.

```
         $..book[*].price.min()
```

but I get the following error :

```
Aggregation function attempted to calculate value using empty array
```

Am I doing something wrong?

What is the correct way to do something like this?

**EDIT : you can test the expressions [here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/)**

Comment: And what do you get? Do simpler expressions work?

Comment: `store` is json object and `book` is json array becareful about them

Comment: Very odd, `$..book[*].price` gives an array of numbers, but adding `.min()` doesn't work.

Comment: This seems to be an open issue.  https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/issues/191

Comment: are you stuck with jsonpath? can i suggest any other solution?

Comment: @abhishek I am not stuck, I can use alternatives

Comment: @Karthik - have you seen my answer?? was it helpful??

http://stackoverflow.com/a/36739781/4626402

Answer (score -1):

The following is your solution written in solution class...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //building your object
    SolutionTo objSolutionTo = new SolutionTo();
    StoreTO objStoreTO = new StoreTO();
    ArrayList<BookTo> objArrayList = new ArrayList<BookTo>();
    BookTo objBookTo = new BookTo();
    objBookTo.setAuthor("Herman Melville");
    objBookTo.setCategory("fiction");
    objBookTo.setTitle("Moby Dick");
    objBookTo.setIsbn("0-553-21311-3");
    objBookTo.setPrice(8.99);
    BookTo objBookTo2 = new BookTo();
    objBookTo2.setAuthor("J. R. R. Tolkien");
    objBookTo2.setCategory("fiction");
    objBookTo2.setTitle("The Lord of the Rings");
    objBookTo2.setIsbn("0-553-21311-3");
    objBookTo2.setPrice(22.99);
    objArrayList.add(objBookTo);
    objArrayList.add(objBookTo2);
    objStoreTO.setBook(objArrayList);
    objSolutionTo.setStore(objStoreTO);
    objSolutionTo.setExpensive(10.0);
    System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(objSolutionTo));


    //The logic you require to find the min value of price
    Double minPrice = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (BookTo bookTo : objSolutionTo.getStore().getBook()) {
        if (minPrice > bookTo.getPrice())
            minPrice = bookTo.getPrice();
    }
    System.out.println(minPrice);
}
```

}

the following is the solutionTO class::

```
public class SolutionTo {
private StoreTO store;
private Double expensive;

public StoreTO getStore() {
    return store;
}

public void setStore(StoreTO store) {
    this.store = store;
}

public Double getExpensive() {
    return expensive;
}

public void setExpensive(Double expensive) {
    this.expensive = expensive;
}

}
```

The following is the StoreTo class::

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StoreTO {
private ArrayList<BookTo> book;

public ArrayList<BookTo> getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(ArrayList<BookTo> book) {
    this.book = book;
}

}
```

The following is the bookTo object::

```
public class BookTo {
private String category;
private String author;
private String title;
private String isbn;
private Double price;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

Run the main method in the solution class you'll find what you wanted...

Happy Helping... :)

Comment: @karthik was this helpful?